# Realm - how to query for a List greater than 0 objects

Tags: swift, realm, predicate

I want all results of Persons that have at least one cat. I tried this:

```
    let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("cats.count > 0")
```

But I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid property name', reason: 'Property 'count' not found in object of type 'Cat''
```

The person object looks like this:

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let cats = List<Cat>()
}
```

What is the proper predicate for this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was so close!

```
    let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("cats.@count > 0")
```

(needed the "@" before `count`)

Comment: Great answer! It's also covered in the documentation for reference [https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries). *The aggregate expressions @ count, @ min, @ max, @ sum and @ avg are supported on List and Results properties, e.g. realm.objects(Company.self).filter("employees.@count > 5") to find all companies with more than five employees.*